# How to dynamically change css styling for a div according to browser screen size

Tags: html, css

am developing an application using the jquery mobile library but i need to apply different styles to a div for desktop browsers and mobile browsers as i want to achieve the same look and feel on both platforms instead of creating different sites for them.

This is the code i wrote for the desktop browser.

```
<div data-role="page" id="chat">
<div data-role="header"><h1>Welcome to the Streamline Chat App</h1></div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin:500px">
<form>
 <label for="username" >Username:</label>
 <input type="text" id="username">
 <label for="pwd" >Password:</label>
 <input type="password" id="pwd">
 <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When the user is using a desktop browser, margin for the main div tag should be 500px. If they are using mobile no margin should be applied. Is there anyway this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading about and using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Your code should be something like:

```
.main {
  margin-left: 500px;
}

/* For mobile screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .main {
       margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Media Query To make it responsive in any screen sizes. Here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Okay no problem. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of media queries. More info can be found at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp. I wanted this as a comment but I need 50 rep so I'll do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="block" style="width:100px;height:100px">
    </div>


    <script>
    function changeStyle(){
        if(window.innerWidth<900){
            document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","mobile.css");

       }else if((window.innerWidth)>900 &&(window.innerWidth)<1200){
         document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","medium.css");   
       }
        else 
              document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","large.css"); 
    }  
    window.onresize=changeStyle;
   changeStyle();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS @meda rules (media queries) that check the properties of the viewport, and write the CSS styles according the the viewport sizes you want.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

For example:

```
<style>
.my_element {
    width: 900px
  }
/*from screen sizes 0px to 600px*/
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .my_element {
    width: 600px
  }
}
</style>
```